Configuring a pgrapqhl schema with NEXUS for use in Cloudflare Workers
I am creating a graphql server for use in cloud workers and when starting the service I am receiving the error below, although the graphql server works, when creating the schema using nexus.
Error:
Error: Root typing path "/src/graphql/context.d.ts" for the type "context" does not exist

Log output in the code
Context path: /src/graphql/context.d.ts
Context file exists: false

schema.ts
import { join } from "node:path";
import { makeSchema } from "nexus";
import * as types from "./types";
import { existsSync } from "node:fs";

const contextPath = join(process.cwd(), "src", "graphql", "context.d.ts");
console.log("Context path:", contextPath);
console.log("Context file exists:", existsSync(contextPath));

const schema = makeSchema({ types: [types], plugins: [], contextType: { module: contextPath, export: "Context", }, outputs: { schema: join(process.cwd(), "./generated/schema.graphql"), typegen: join(process.cwd(), "./generated/nexus-typegen.d.ts"), }, });

export { schema };
``` context.d.ts ``` export type Context = { user: string;
 // prism: PrismaClient;
};

The 2 files are in the same directory ./src/graphql
As I mentioned, although the graphql server starts without problems, the console displays this error, and I can't find a solution to fix it.
I've already searched the documentation for cloudflare workers and nexus, but I haven't found anything that could solve the error.
